# SSH into Django Shell

Tags: python, django, ssh

I'm attempting to write a simple one-line script to ssh into a remote host, CD to my Django app's directory, and run `manage.py shell`. So far I have:

```
ssh -i mysite.pem root@remotehost "cd /usr/local/myapp; /bin/bash -i -c \"python manage.py shell;\""
```

This seems to work with the caveat that I can't see any output from my commands. All I see is:

```
Python 2.6.4 (r264:75706, Jun  4 2010, 18:20:16) 
[GCC 4.4.4 20100503 (Red Hat 4.4.4-2)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
(InteractiveConsole)
```

And then any input I give, but when I press enter, I don't seem to see anything from stdout. However, if I enter syntactically invalid Python, I do see a Python traceback from stderr.

What else am I missing?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Pass the `-t` option to `ssh`.

> Force pseudo-tty allocation. This can be used to execute arbitrary screen-based programs on a remote machine, which can be very useful, e.g. when implementing menu services. Multiple -t options force tty allocation, even if ssh has no local tty.

By default, running `ssh host command` doesn't allocate a proper pseudo-tty, which makes any program that uses terminal escape routines, such as line-editing interpreters, etc. fail.

Therefore, your one-liner can be:

```
ssh -t -i mysite.pem root@remotehost python /usr/local/myapp/manage.py shell
```

It is possible to, but no need to wrap in another layer of bash like you did. Remember that `ssh host command` actually passes `command` as a string to the user's default shell (which is why you can do shell-specific things like `cd`), so I can't think of a reason why you'll need to run `bash` within `bash`.

Comment: The "Very interesting question!

I'm experimenting right now to find an answer, and will edit it to add more as I go" part isn't helpful.  Can you remove it and boil this down to the answer without the colorful commentary?

Comment: There's no need for the `cd <path>` part, just doing `ssh -t -i mysite.pem root@remotehost 'python /usr/local/myapp/manage.py shell'`

Comment: Oh, okay, that's even better. I had assumed that the OP had the `cd` in place because `manage.py` relied on the working directory being the django project's directory.